# Functionally (ie. immutably) updating a Racket object

Tags: class, object, racket

Say I define a class in Racket with about 30 fields.

And I want to treat these as immutable. In other words I never update the object in place, just create a new object with 29 of the fields containing the same values and one with the over-written value.

Are there any convenience functions to do this?

At the moment I'm rather laboriously writing a function like

```
(define/public (overwrite-n n-val) 
    (new MyClass% [a (get-a)] [b (get-b)] [c (get-c)] ... [n n-val] ... ))
```

for each field I want to be able to update. There must be a better way to do this.

Comment: Never use `class` in Racket, but there's a package called `my-object` (https://docs.racket-lang.org/my-object/index.html) with JavaScript-like object system. It has `object-extend` which could extend the object immutably. This might be what you want if you don't really need `class`.

Comment: I don't think there are any convenience functions to do that with the current `racket/class` system. For structs, there's `struct-copy`, which works because struct identifiers have compile-time bindings that can tell the macro what to do. The racket class system doesn't have that advantage though.

Comment: I am incredibly biased against OOP, but despite being a huge fan of Racket, I would personally avoid `racket/class`. It is perfectly capable, but it does not play nice with the style of programming I strive for, which tends to be rather functional. As suggested here, I would try to build your abstractions using structs if at all possible—using `racket/generic` may help with that.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do functional update like this, you would probably be better off using structs, where tools like [`struct-copy`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/struct-copy.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._struct-copy%29%29) and [generic interfaces](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/struct-generics.html) are there provided for you.

If you do need to use `racket/class`, then one option, if these are public fields and they are all declared with `init-field`, is using reflection mechanisms and private `racket/class` implementation details like `class-info` and `do-make-object` from `racket/private/class-internal`. For fun, I made an `object-copy` form similar to `struct-copy`, which is in a gist here: [object-copy.rkt](https://gist.github.com/AlexKnauth/65d3f0c40dec751dd391)

```
#lang racket/base

(require racket/class
         "object-copy.rkt")

(define my-class%
  (class object%
    (super-new)
    (inspect #f)
    (init-field a b c)

    (define/public (get-a) a)
    (define/public (get-b) b)
    (define/public (get-c) c)

    (define/public (update-a a)
      (object-copy my-class% this [a a]))
    (define/public (update-b b)
      (object-copy my-class% this [b b]))
    (define/public (update-c c)
      (object-copy my-class% this [c c]))
    ))

(define obj
  (new my-class%
       [a 1]
       [b 2]
       [c 3]))

(send obj get-a)
; 1
(send (send obj update-a 4) get-a)
; 4
```

Another option, if you can be sure that these will *always* be true:

- Your class won't ever have any initialization arguments
- Its subclasses won't either
- In the rest of the methods, the only way you access those fields is with the getter methods

Then you can override the getter methods to get that behavior:

```
#lang racket/base

(require racket/class)

(define my-class%
  (class object%
    (super-new)

    (define/public (get-a) (error 'a "uninitialized"))
    (define/public (get-b) (error 'b "uninitialized"))
    (define/public (get-c) (error 'c "uninitialized"))

    (define/public (update-a a)
      (new (class this%
             (super-new)
             (define/override (get-a) a))))
    (define/public (update-b b)
      (new (class this%
             (super-new)
             (define/override (get-b) b))))
    (define/public (update-c c)
      (new (class this%
             (super-new)
             (define/override (get-c) c))))
    ))

(define obj
  (send+ (new my-class%)
         (update-a 1)
         (update-b 2)
         (update-c 3)))

(send obj get-a)
; 1
(send (send obj update-a 4) get-a)
; 4
```

If those things aren't true, or you're afraid that someday you'll forget and they'll change (pretty likely, especially with the subclass thing), then this won't work. Using `this%` isn't really type-safe if it can be subclassed.

Although like I said at the top of this answer, structs are usually better for this type of thing.

Comment: Like Alex said: use structs! Use structs!